# gcc does not work

Tags: gcc

I just copy gcc from another Fedora and put it in my Fedora.

In the other Fedora, if I do:

```
./gcc
i586-meego-linux-gnu-gcc: no input files
```

but for me, if I do:

```
./gcc
//there is nothing
```

What could be wrong? I'm sure if I do: file ./gcc and ldd ./gcc and ls -all ./gcc, they are the same.

Comment: What *precisely* did you copy? If you mean just the `gcc` executable, it won't work on a machine that does't have the GNU compiler collection installed -- the executable would have nothing to invoke. For the `gcc` front end to work, you need a compiler, a linker, a standard library, standard header files, and so on -- the entire collection is required.

Comment: I just have copied a completed toolchain of meego. If I run gcc of the system, it seems fine. only the gcc from the toolChain.

Comment: Why can't you install with `sudo yum install gcc` ?

Comment: I have done it. i am running gcc from a toolChain to build for a specific platform

Answer (score 0):

Compiler should fit your computer's architecture. If your computer is x86, and you copied another, like i586 or arm, it sure won't run properly.

Comment: the architecture of the both PC are the same: Fedora x64